# Error while reading a CSV file

Tags: r

Declaring variable types separately using colclasses parameters

```
varTypes <- c(
  Sepal.Length = 'Numeric', 
  Sepal.Width = 'Numeric', 
  Petal.Length = 'Numeric', 
  Petal.Width = 'Numeric', 
  Species = "Factor", 
  Name = "Character"
)


Flowers <- read.table(
  "C:/Study/JIGSAW/irisone.csv", 
  header=FALSE, 
  sep=",", 
  skip = 1, 
  col.names=names(varTypes), 
  colClasses = varTypes
)
```

Error message is displayed below:

```
Error in methods::as(data[[i]], colClasses[i]) : 
  no method or default for coercing “character” to “Numeric”
```

Comment: try `numeric` with a lower case "n" in varTypes (same for Factor and Character, while you're at it)

Comment: You should keep in mind that EVERYTHING in R is case sensitive. If you get an error that says something like "cannot find" or "no method", the first thing you should do is check your capitalization and spelling.

Comment: You can always use the import wizard.  Under environment tab click Import Dataset.  You can specify variable types there and it will generate code to paste into your script.

Comment: Thanks you so much it worked, thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

Try `numeric` with a lower case "n" in varTypes (same for Factor and Character, while you're at it)

Comment: Yes it worked when I made the changes as you suggested ..cheers!!

Comment: @samjigsaw412 glad to hear it. I'd appreciate if you upvote and/or mark the answer as accepted (the little check mark under the votes). (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)